# How to turn off project mirroring from SourcForge to launchpad?

Tags: import, mirror, sourceforge, launchpad

I have project [Emle](https://launchpad.net/emle) in [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/). I set it to import from [emle.svn.sourceforge.net](https://emle.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/emle/trunk/). My intention was to do a single import of the files from SourceForge.

[Emle>Branches>2.0](https://code.launchpad.net/~cwhii/emle/2.0) shows that what I actually did was set it to mirror the SourceForge project.

```
Import details
Import Status: Reviewed
This branch is an import of the Subversion branch from https://emle.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/emle/trunk.

The next import is scheduled to run in 35 minutes.  
Last successful import was 5 hours ago.

 Import started 5 hours ago on russkaya and finished 5 hours ago taking 30 seconds — see the log
 Import started 12 hours ago on neumayer and finished 12 hours ago taking 30 seconds — see the log
 Import started 20 hours ago on russkaya and finished 20 hours ago taking 30 seconds — see the log
```

How can I turn off the mirroring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is no interface for this other than to post a question on the [launchpad.net](http://launchpad.net) [Questions and Answers](https://answers.launchpad.net/) page. For example, see question [104693](https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad-code/+question/104693) with a day or two for the response.